# Vectorize test for nan

Tags: c++, gcc, nan, simd, intrinsics

It is quite easy to select a value based on a condition mask with for example less than or greater than:

```
using vec4_t __attribute__((vector_size(4*sizeof(float)))) = float;

inline auto chooseValIfInRange(vec4_t val, vec4_t if_too_small, vec4_t if_too_large)
{
    return val < vec4_t{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}?
        val_small
        : (val > vec4_t{1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}?
            val_large : val);
}
```

The above will return `if_too_small` for vector components less than 0.0f, `if_too_large` if the vector component is greater than 1.0f, and val if it is between 0.0f and 1.0f inclusive. Would it be possible to choose a third value for nan without any branch? If so, how?

Comment: Remark: you don't need to create explicitly a vector of 0s, g++ understands `val < 0.0f` just fine. I see you have the tag "intrinsics", does that mean you are interested in an x86-only answer using `_mm_*` functions?

Comment: @MargClisse: It means that I would accept such an answer (for now at least, since I am targeting my amd64 PC).

Answer (score 4):

You can exploit the fact that only for `val=NaN` both `val>=0` and `val<=1` are false:

```
using vec4_t __attribute__((vector_size(4*sizeof(float)))) = float;
    
auto chooseValIfInRange(vec4_t val, vec4_t val_small, vec4_t val_large, vec4_t val_nan)
{
    return val >=  0.0f
        ? ( val <= 1.0f ? val       : val_large)
        : ( val <= 1.0f ? val_small : val_nan  )
    ;
}
```

The `val <= 1.0f` comparison will be executed only once when optimizations are enabled: https://godbolt.org/z/Pcjezq

Comment: @MarcGlisse True, but the question actually did not ask anything about -ffast-math. If that is activated, I agree with your comments, that you are in UB territory ...

Comment: Oh sorry, I was mislead by the discussions elsewhere, you are right. Using the same val<=1 in both branches is a nice trick!

Answer (score 0):

Using `f != f` will be true only if f is NaN

(untested code)

```cpp
inline auto chooseValIfInRange(vec4_t val, vec4_t if_too_small, vec4_t if_too_large)
{
    return val < vec4_t{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}?
        val_small
        : (val > vec4_t{1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}?
            val_large 
        : ((val != val) ? val_nan : val));
}
```

Comment: This works, but not if fast-math is turned on. Is it possible to make it work with fast-math?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, fast-math is you telling the compiler that you don't care about NaN (among other things).

Comment: Assume that I get a nan from outside, it would then be UB to call the function with that value. I found a solution that appears to work in gcc:

auto __attribute__((optimize("-fno-fastmath"))) chooseValIfInRange(vec4_t val, vec4_t if_too_small, vec4_t if_too_large, vec4_t if_nan)

It looks correct in compiler explorer but I get a warning: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/38bzfc

Comment: The warning is pretty clear, you misspelled -fno-fast-math. That would work, but it might have unintended consequences (preventing function inlining, or disabling fast-math in the whole function this gets inlined into). If you have a NaN anywhere with fast-math, you already have undefined behavior.

Comment: What I am worried about is that vdivps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm1 would produce nan in case both xmm0 and xmm1 are zero, which is possible if they are loaded from memory (ultimately user input). Is the compiler self-consistent here in the sense that instructions that may cause nan for at least some combination of inputs are banned?

Comment: @user877329 don't use the comments to ask entirely new questions. Your original post does not mention `-ffast-math` at all.

Comment: With fast-math, you are responsible for avoiding operations like 0./0., you need to check for such conditions *before* doing the operation. This is similar to integer overflow.

Comment: If you care about things like NaN, never use -ffast-math.

Comment: I think this would solve the problem with compiler options: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a9qdo7. I also checked the code with disableinging opt for the particular function, and indeed, it cannot be inlined anymore. I do not think it is a major perf hit in this particular context. The code will do 4 mem loads to fetch pixel data, and then do a lookup in the color table. But disabling it means that the code won't compile with finite-math-only.